# How to find (latest) descendant revision of given ( possibly renamed ) file

Tags: mercurial

Assuming a hg repository with arbitrary changes incl file renames/copies.

Some time in the past I picked an arbitrary file revision from repo and noted down it’s changeset/revision :

File A revision 2 changed with changeset aaabbbccceeefffggg

I now ( after several possible committed changes ) want to know which current file in my repo is descendant of the original noted file/revision.
For example the following file history ( incl. renames of A ) :

```
C tip ( renamed from B rev 7 )
B 7
B 6
B 5
B 4 ( renamed from A rev 3 )
A 3
A 2
A 1
```

Starting point of my problem is file A revision 2.
How do I traverse to C ( find out the path C and get revision of C too ) ?
Problem is hat A is currently not visible at all in my repo ( because it was renamed to something else ) :

```
hg log --follow A
abort: cannot follow file not in parent revision: "A"
```

Somehow I need a reversed “--follow”, i.e. going up the version history (future) instead of down (past).

Answer (score 0):

Update to revision 2 and than call the log --follow command.

I did not tried it, but the message "cannot follow file not in parent revision" suggests that the file should be in the parent of the working directory.